# How to decode raw formatted Gmail API get messages to extract links

Tags: python, api, base64, gmail

Attempting to get a gmail message given a message id. I retrieve the message as a raw type and attempt to decode it in base64 and then use the links that are held within the email. The message appears to be decoded somewhat but there seems like useless bytes and the URLs are all still invalid.

```
def GetMessageWithId(service, user_id, msg_id, format):
    try:
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id,
                                                 id=msg_id,
                                                 format=format).execute()
        msg_str = str(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message["raw"].encode("ASCII")))
        return msg_str
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print("An error occurred: %s" % error)
```

When I examine `msg_str`, I can see where the links are located but if I try to copy them and put them into a browser they are invalid.

I then try to use beautiful soup to locate the `href` tags within the `msg_str`. However, the links that are found look something like this:

> 3D"https://post.pinterest=\r\n.com/f/a/WRi5L7G_wfTW1BovkyUGuw~~/AAAAAQA~/RgRe6WEYPwRXCXBpbnRlcmVzdEIKABwY=\r\n3AZdrwvFllIXdHVyZ2VvbmNocmlzM0BnbWFpbC5jb21YBAAAAAA~?target=3Dhttps%3A%2F%2=\r\nFwww.pinterest.com%2Fsecure%2Fautologin%2F%3Fod%3DFux7G1fLpQxdgu%252FAlq7%2=\r\n52FO0wnXhG3mrIvODBVUav9ko5yjUdnc84zWzwWN%252BPJyxYElh86K0WCnm9Th%252F6kUWW%=\r\n252FfcKmC7yJz0qo50Ss4EaaUahZGfo19MQS%252BIeP4Dlvz0hgCjvxIS4R%252BPMAF%252FG=\r\nl9BpWrQ%253D%253D%26user_id%3DNjEwMDk3MjE4MTc4OTE0MjA0%26next%3D%252Fpin%25=\r\n2F806707351985179613%252F%253Futm_campaign%253Dpopular_pins%2526e_t%253De5a=\r\nb90da0abf493b944b3c27261acfe3%2526utm_content%253D806707351985179613%2526ut=\r\nm_source%253D31%2526utm_term%253D1%2526utm_medium%253D2012

I would expect that the entire raw email would be able to be decoded into html but it seems that only parts of the email are. I will attach a link to Gmail's documentation for this get message https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like quoted-printable encoded text which has been urlencoded.

```
import quopri
from urllib import parse

s = 'href%3D"https://post.pinterest=\r\n.com/f/a/WRi5L7G_wfTW1BovkyUGuw~~/AAAAAQA~/RgRe6WEYPwRXCXBpbnRlcmVzdEIKABwY=\r\n3AZdrwvFllIXdHVyZ2VvbmNocmlzM0BnbWFpbC5jb21YBAAAAAA~?target=3Dhttps%3A%2F%2=\r\nFwww.pinterest.com%2Fsecure%2Fautologin%2F%3Fod%3DFux7G1fLpQxdgu%252FAlq7%2=\r\n52FO0wnXhG3mrIvODBVUav9ko5yjUdnc84zWzwWN%252BPJyxYElh86K0WCnm9Th%252F6kUWW%=\r\n252FfcKmC7yJz0qo50Ss4EaaUahZGfo19MQS%252BIeP4Dlvz0hgCjvxIS4R%252BPMAF%252FG=\r\nl9BpWrQ%253D%253D%26user_id%3DNjEwMDk3MjE4MTc4OTE0MjA0%26next%3D%252Fpin%25=\r\n2F806707351985179613%252F%253Futm_campaign%253Dpopular_pins%2526e_t%253De5a=\r\nb90da0abf493b944b3c27261acfe3%2526utm_content%253D806707351985179613%2526ut=\r\nm_source%253D31%2526utm_term%253D1%2526utm_medium%253D2012'

parse.unquote_plus(quopri.decodestring(s).decode('utf-8'))
'href="https://post.pinterest.com/f/a/WRi5L7G_wfTW1BovkyUGuw~~/AAAAAQA~/RgRe6WEYPwRXCXBpbnRlcmVzdEIKABwY3AZdrwvFllIXdHVyZ2VvbmNocmlzM0BnbWFpbC5jb21YBAAAAAA~?target=https://www.pinterest.com/secure/autologin/?od=Fux7G1fLpQxdgu%2FAlq7%2FO0wnXhG3mrIvODBVUav9ko5yjUdnc84zWzwWN%2BPJyxYElh86K0WCnm9Th%2F6kUWW%2FfcKmC7yJz0qo50Ss4EaaUahZGfo19MQS%2BIeP4Dlvz0hgCjvxIS4R%2BPMAF%2FGl9BpWrQ%3D%3D&user_id=NjEwMDk3MjE4MTc4OTE0MjA0&next=%2Fpin%2F806707351985179613%2F%3Futm_campaign%3Dpopular_pins%26e_t%3De5ab90da0abf493b944b3c27261acfe3%26utm_content%3D806707351985179613%26utm_source%3D31%26utm_term%3D1%26utm_medium%3D2012'
```